# SOLR finding exact field(s) information

Tags: solr, lucene

After  field query execution, for given search term(s), SOLR APIs are returning the doc Ids.
My question is there a way to  fetch minimal set of fields which contains only end user search terms?

For example, I have a SOLR document with nearly 200 attributes
My query is (name:SOLR* OR Description:LUCENE*) AND (Publisher:Print*  OR AUTHOR:ERIC etc)

In the above example, if name field matches, i want only name and so on

Comment: What about &fl=name,Description,Publisher,AUTHOR combined with highlighting?

Comment: Building on the above, I think perhaps `&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.fragsize=0` would do the trick. Please keep in mind that only stored fields will be returned with highlighting.

Comment: fl simply returns all the fields. I am looking for conditional  fields.  If "Description" is not matching, i dont want to see. This is the reason, FL will not fit the needs.

Comment: &fl=name,Description,Publisher,AUTHOR  ....  returns all 4 fields on the search results. But i don't want all 4.  i want only fields that contain the search criteria.